# Load while scrolling down like Instagram or any app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I currently have an Xcode project that loads data and puts them in arrays that will be sorted through and placed on a table. As of now when I go to the table in the viewDidLoad() part, I have a function that will gather all of the data I need. But to stop the app from crashing it loads a limit of 30. My current problem is that once the user scrolls through the 30 items, I want 30 more to be loaded beneath the initially 30 (standard scrolling). The only way I can think about doing this is reloading the whole table which is not very smart.

I just want a standard scrolling feature that you see in apps like Instagram, Facebook, or any internet app that loads data on a tableview. So as the user is scrolling, more data is being added to the bottom. Below I have copied my code the I use to gather the initial data:

```
    func findAnimalUsers() {
        //STEP 1: Find users
                let animalQuery = PFQuery(className: "Animals") //choosing class
                animalQuery.whereKey("dog", equalTo: animalType.text!) //getting users with animal type user types
                animalQuery.limit = 30 //number of users intitally showing
                animalQuery.findObjectsInBackground (block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil { //if no error

                        //clean up
                        self.animalArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                        //STEP 2: Find related objects depending on query setting
                        for object in objects! {
                            self.animalArray.append(object.value(forKey: "user") as! String) //objectId of related users
                        }

                        //STEP 3: Find users
                        let query = PFUser.query()
                        query?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: self.animalArray) //finding users
                        query?.addDescendingOrder("createdAt") //how to order users
                        query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {

                                //clean up
                                self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)                                                   

                                self.profilePhotoArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                                self.objectIDArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                                //find related objects depending on query setting
                                for object in objects! {
                                    self.usernameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "username") as! String)
                                    self.profilePhotoArray.append(object.object(forKey: "profilePhoto") as! PFFile)
                                    self.objectIDArray.append(object.objectId!)

                                }
                            } else {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                    } else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }
```

I have also added the code of how the table uses this information:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //define cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! AnimalsCell

        //STEP 1: connect data from server to objects
        cell.usernameLabel.text = usernameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.objectID = objectIDArray[indexPath.row]
        profilePhotoArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground (block: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                cell.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(data: data!)                
            } else {
                print(error)
            }            
        })
```

So when this view controller comes up in viewDidLoad(), I just have findAnimalUsers() in it to start the initial load. **How do I load more while scrolling down???**

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate method of scrollview

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
    if offsetY >= contentHeight - scrollHeight
    {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and in my logic I made it skip the query by the number of items in the array that decides how many rows should be in the table. But when I start to scroll, it loads multiple duplicates. `animalQuery.skip = objectIDArray.count` How do I fix this???

Comment: @fphelp In your case objectId should be unique so when you scroll your last objectId will be your first for next 30 fetching data; Like if you have now last objectId is 30 then in your next scroll you will load data from objectId 31 and then you will append data in array and reload table after appending data so that you will not get duplicate data..

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure I understand what you are fully trying to say. To get the number of rows needed in the table, it counts the objects in the array `objectIDArray.count`. **Should I not have the code skip by the same array I use to populate the number of rows?**

Comment: I want to say that store your last count of array in the integer variable so when you scroll again you will use that stored variable count to start load the next data..

Comment: I am still getting duplicates how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that with the delegate method of `tableView`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell , forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == lastElement {
        // handle your logic here to get more items, add it to dataSource and reload tableview
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but the build fails and it highlights `lastElement` with the error saying: "Use of unresolved identifier 'lastElement'" How can I fix this?

Comment: lastElement is just a reference here, you have to define first in your code and set it to last indexpath from the list of your items.

Comment: In short lastElement = <your table data>.count and that you have to define globally in your class.

Comment: To get the number of rows in the project counts the amount of object in an array I made. So I change `lastElement` to `objectIDArray.count ` then inside the parentheses I use the same code to get the next objects, but this time I have it skip by `objectIDArray.count` so I do not load ones that are already there. **But when I try this, nothing happens and nothing new is loaded.** What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I put it all in a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665796/load-while-scrolling-down-like-any-app

Comment: need help regarding this